# "Take the train" vs "Get in/out the train" vs "Get on/off the train" which one is right?

Tags: expressions

I have a question about some verbs - take in, take out, get in, get out, get on and get off.

Assuming a passenger is boarding a train or an airplane,
Which one is right expression among these verbs: take, get in and get on?

On the other hand, assuming a passenger is unboarding from the train or the airplane,
Which one is right expression amond these verbs: get out, get off?

Are there any differences between "get off" and "get out", and between "get on" and "get in"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand a little on Dale M's answer and answer the questions in your comment on that answer:

"Get the train" is similar to "take the train" in that it refers to the *concept* of travelling by train to a specific destination rather than the physical action of boarding it. Having said that it refers more to arriving at the station in time and having a ticket for the journey than "take the train" does. In your example the tannoy announcement "**Passengers getting the bus for Manchester please go to stand 5**" would be meaningful. The passengers would need to be at the bus station to hear the announcement and they may need to have their tickets if the places on the bus were pre-booked. The announcement "**Passengers getting the bus *bound* for Manchester please go to Stand 5**" has exactly the same meaning.

Having said that there are other forms of expression relating to the use of public transport.

1. "Catch the train/bus/plane" means to arrive at the departure point before the transport has left and usually before the doors have closed so that you can actually board it. A bus driver will often reopen the door for you, a train guard will rarely re-open the door and if you arrive at the gate at an airport after the flight has closed you will not be allowed on. It is possible to arrive at a railway station just too late and be standing next to the train you meant to catch as it leaves without you. In that case you have **missed** the train which is the opposite of **catching**  it.
2. We often refer to transport omitting the word **for** altogether and using the destination as an adjective. For example the tannoy request above would be in the form of "Passengers for the Manchester bus please go to stand 5". To make it more specific the scheduled departure time is also used as well so that we say things like "I'm booked on the 11:40 for Manchester" and aircraft are referred to by flight number. **BA927** for example will be a scheduled flight leaving a specific airport for another specific airport at the same time every day. It won't always be the same plane but it will always intend to fly between the same airports and will, usually, be the same model so that it can carry the same number of passengers.

I believe that the use of "get on" for public transport is related to the nature of public transport before passenger trains were developed. The main forms of transport were the "carrier's cart" for local journeys and the stage coach for longer ones. Carrier's carts were a variety of vehicles, being whatever the person who had set himself up as the village carrier had available, but were mostly, if not exclusively, open carts. Sometimes they would even be flat carts with no sides and people would refer to "getting onto" the cart. Similarly there were far more "outsider" passengers than "insider" passengers on stage coaches. There was more space outside on top of the coach than there was inside and on wealthy people could afford to travel inside. To travel outside you had to "get on" rather than "get into" the coach.

Even after the introduction of passenger trains the cheapest seats were in open carriages and the least wealthy used them. They would have "got onto" these carriages in the same way as they "got onto" the carrier's cart or the outside of a stagecoach.

Cars and taxis were originally used exclusively by the wealthy who would be used to travelling inside coaches and closed railway carriages so they would, naturally, have talked about getting "into" a car or taxi.

Aeroplanes, because they are scheduled and carry unrelated passengers, are more like trains and buses than cars and taxis so we talk about "getting onto" a plane. Also international travel for the British involved ships before there were aeroplanes and we have usually talked about "getting on" a ship as people used to board on a open deck then "go below" if appropriate.

Comment: British railway staff and passengers may talk about _boarding_ a train at the start of a journey, and _alighting from_ it when the destination is reached.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I didn't include "boarding" (which also has it's origins in shipping) because the OP includes "boarding" in the question.

Comment: Greengrocer's apostrophe!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Quite right, don't know what I was thinking of! Probably half asleep.

Answer (score 0):

### Take

"Take the train" is a reference to the entire journey by train. For example: "How will you get to London?" "I will take the train/bus/plane."

### Get on/off, Get in/out

These are largely interchangeable. On and off have the general connotation that one is on top of something while in and out have the connotation of being within in. As such, it would be odd to tell someone to "get in the horse", while "get on the horse" is perfectly sensible. Of most other forms of public transport, because they have an inside and an outside, get in/out works and because they are to some extent elevated above the ground and also because they are the successor of the horse, get on/off works as well. However, one would not usually say "get on the car".

Comment: I appreciate for the specific answer. I have more questions. (1) How about the expression "get the train" (without on/in)? does it still the meaning the action that a passenger is boarding? (2) Is this sentence right expression: "Passengers getting the bus bound for (...), please go to (somewhere)"?

Comment: To really be helpful this answer should be expanded to cover many more cases.  As it is, saying they are largely interchangeable is more than a little misleading.